# Stuck at boot Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: boot, 23.04

Please tell me what to do step by step. These are the images.

https://linksharing.samsungcloud.com/7Pj1WEzsfRlj
https://linksharing.samsungcloud.com/5P2qx5Sshyby

[image]

[image]